# Unable to link with undefined reference to VTT for CryptoPP::RSAFunction

Tags: c++, arm64, crypto++

I'm using Crypto++ on aarch64, I'm facing a problem when compiling my binary which use cryptopp-7.0.0, the only link problem I face is related to `RSAFunction`, all the other classes worked perfectly, here is the program itself which is really a basic one that isolate the problem:

```cxx
#include "cryptopp/rsa.h"
using CryptoPP::RSA;

#include <string.h>
using std::string;

#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile with this command:

```
~$ toolchain/bin/aarch64-libreelec-linux-gnueabi-g++ cryptopptestfile.cpp -o crypttest -L/toolchain/usr/lib -lcryptopp
```

I got those errors:

```
<artificial>:(.text+0xe7c): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::RSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0xe80): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::RSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0xea8): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::RSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0xeb4): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::RSAFunction'
/tmp/ccs498WJ.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction::~InvertibleRSAFunction()':
<artificial>:(.text+0x10c0): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x10c4): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x10c8): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x112c): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
/tmp/ccs498WJ.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction::InvertibleRSAFunction()':
<artificial>:(.text+0x12e4): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x12f8): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x1324): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x132c): undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x13cc): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
<artificial>:(.text+0x13dc): undefined reference to `VTT for CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction'
```

This is only related to :

```
cryptopp::RSAFunction(s)
```

Thanks for help.

Here is the compilation flags:

```
arch64-libreelec-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv8-a+crc+fp+simd -mabi=lp64 -Wno-psabi -mcpu=cortex-a53+crc+fp+simd -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -pipe -Os -flto -ffat-lto-objects -fPIC -pipe -c rsa.cpp
```

g++ version:

```
6.2.0
```

Comment: Also see [How to ensure C++ classes don't go missing with -flto?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2019-01/msg00109.html) on the GCC-Help mailing list.

Comment: I have added the gcc version along with compilation flags, so that it gives more clues for GCC mailing list

Comment: We regularly test with `-Os` in [`cryptest.sh`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh#L3704), which is our test script from hell. `-Os` causes a lot of problems compared to other optimization options, like `-O3` or `-O5`. You might trying using `-O3` and `-flto` and avoiding `-Os`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue identified, it is because of this compilation flag :

```
-flto
```

As soon as I remove this compiling flag, everything works normal, please note that activating this flag which is:

```
-flto:
This option runs the standard link-time optimizer. When invoked with 
source code, it generates GIMPLE (one of GCC’s internal representations) 
and writes it to special ELF sections in the object file. When the object 
files are linked together, all the function bodies are read from these ELF 
sections and instantiated as if they had been part of the same translation 
unit.
```

This flag breaks the linker when using RSAFunction(s), tested from version 6.0.0 to 8.0.0